# Samba permissions settings ignored?

Tags: permissions, samba, thunderbird

I have a CentOS 6.4 fileserver running SerNet Samba 4.0.9 with these 
global settings (not overridden):

```
    read only = No
    force create mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    inherit acls = yes
    inherit owner = yes
    inherit permissions = yes
```

On a Windows client, I have Thunderbird 24.0 storing its profile and 
mail on the Samba share.  The perms on everything in the share were 
chmod -R 777'd.

Then I get mail, compact a folder, whatever, and it looks like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513        0 Oct 18  2012 Archives
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513     3158 Sep 25 13:20 Archives.msf
drwxrwxrwx. 2 1128 513     4096 Sep 25 09:12 Archives.sbd
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513        0 Sep 25 13:49 Drafts
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513     2450 Sep 25 13:50 Drafts.msf
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513        0 Sep 25 13:08 Inbox
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513     2317 Sep 25 13:50 Inbox.msf
drwxrwxrwx. 3 1128 513     4096 May 28 09:26 Inbox.sbd
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513     1268 Apr 12  2007 Junk.msf
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513       28 Oct  2  2012 msgFilterRules.dat
-rwxrwxrwx  1 1128 513    13736 Sep 25 13:50 popstate.dat
-rwxrwxrwx  1 1128 513 96061164 Sep 25 13:21 Sent
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513  2988277 Sep 25 13:21 Sent.msf
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513        0 Mar 25  2010 Templates
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1128 513     2684 Sep 25 13:20 Templates.msf
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513        0 Sep 25 13:50 Trash
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1128 513     2223 Sep 25 13:50 Trash.msf
```

Whatever it touches is now 770.  How can that be, when the parent of 
this folder is 777, Samba is set to inherit and force 0777?